# Launch .NET Core project in VS Code using dotnet run

Tags: visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli

We have a .net core 2.0 project that we've been using in Visual Studio. I want to switch to using VS Code. I updated the launchsettings.json to include a Project launch profile (instead of IIS) and made the necessary changes to be able to use the dotnet cli to run it.

However, when I try to launch it in VS Code I don't see where the dotnet run is being used because I want to use that command to run the project since we need to pass a configuration to that command in order for it to work. The command line looks like this:

```
dotnet run -c Dev --launch-profile Project
```

I don't know how to set up vs code to launch using the above command.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this or a way to get the behaviour you wanted?